# SDL_AddTimer does it hog CPU usage?

Tags: sdl, sdl-2

I am not sure if i use the SDL_AddTimer, for 1ms delay each time of invoking, does it hog CPU?

```
my_timer_id = SDL_AddTimer(delay, my_callbackfunc, my_callback_param);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Timers usually run in separate thread, so you getting a lot of task-switching with this. Same as with `SDL_Delay`, it isn't guarantee that your process will sleep specified time, - rather *at least*  specified time.

So, the answer for your question is - timers aren't come for free. There will be a cost for their frequent usage, but it is unlikely that you'll notice it. But since you can't rely on timer interval, it isn't looks like a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Why do u say we can not rely on timer interval?

Comment: SDL manual (generally speaking, it is OS related, not SDL): "The granularity of the timer is platform-dependent, but you should count  on  it being  at  least 10 ms as this is the most common number. This means that if you request a 16 ms timer, your callback will run approximately 20 ms  later  on  an unloaded  system"

Comment: Exact number (which comes from OS's scheduler frequency) may vary between different OSes, kernel versions, or settings. Also, under heavy loaded system scheduler may skip your process/thread and give CPU time to another process, leaving you to wait for another re-scheduling (another 10 ms, in given example).

Comment: Keltar, so, it looks like, using timer is may not guarantee fixed time interval as it depends on other system loads also. right ?

Comment: Yes. But even if you don't use timers and delays - your program isn't guaranteed to always have CPU time. Sometimes it will be suspended to free CPU time for other processes. This is how multi-tasking operating systems work. It gets a bit easier with many-core CPUs, tho.

Comment: Thanks for consistent reply.